# Flutter - Push notification on realtime database firebase using with cloud function error

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to do push notification on realtime database firebase by using cloud function with flutter app but got this error after deploy. And I am not sure that code right or not because I am not really understanding the flow. I already successfully insert data to database and the problem is to using cloud function to send notification that data onchange to app back.

[2022-08-20T05:04:16.312Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND"."}

here code on my cloud function

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.notifyTrigger =
functions.database.ref("Users/{uid}").onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  if (snapshot.empty) {
    console.log("No Devices");
    return;
  }
});

const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: "Message from Cloud",
    body: "This is your body",
    badge: "1",
    sound: "default",
  },
};

return admin.database().ref("Users").once("value").then((allToken) => {
  if (allToken.val()) {
    console.log("token available");
    const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
  } else {
    console.log("No token available");
  }
});
```

this is from my flutter app main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
    // description
    importance: Importance.high,
    playSound: true);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('A bg message just showed up :  ${message.messageId}');
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Firebase Push Notification',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Firebase Push Notification'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final userNameController = TextEditingController();
  final userAgeController = TextEditingController();
  final userSalaryController = TextEditingController();

  DatabaseReference dbRef;

  _getToken(){
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((deviceToken){
      print("Device Token: $deviceToken");
    });
  }

  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getToken();
    dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('Users');

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('onMessage: $message');
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channelDescription: channel.description,
                color: Colors.blue,
                playSound: true,
                icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
              ),
            ));
      }
    });


    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
      print('onMessage: $message');
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text(notification.title),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [Text(notification.body)],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    });
  }

  void showNotification() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        "Testing $_counter",
        "How you doin ?",
        NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(channel.id, channel.name,
                channelDescription: channel.description,
                importance: Importance.high,
                color: Colors.blue,
                playSound: true,
                icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher')));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool showFab = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        title: Text(widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              const Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: userNameController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Name',
                  hintText: 'Enter Your Name',
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: userAgeController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Age',
                  hintText: 'Enter Your Age',
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Map<String, String> users = {
                    'name': userNameController.text,
                    'age': userAgeController.text,
                  };

                  dbRef.push().set(users);

                  userNameController.clear();
                  userAgeController.clear();
                },
                color: Colors.orange[700],
                textColor: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                ),
                minWidth: 300,
                height: 45,
                child: const Text('Insert Data to Firebase'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Visibility(
      visible: !showFab,
      child: buildMessageButton(),
    ),// This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
  Widget buildMessageButton() => FloatingActionButton.extended(
    backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
    icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
    onPressed: showNotification,
    tooltip: 'Increment', label: Text('Test Local Notification'),
  );
}
```

Here image of my flutter app

[image: flutter app]

But I am not really get it what is my column name in firebase database because the column show token instead of column name. So I just try like this

```
functions.database.ref("Users/{uid}")
```

Comment: Have you referred to these [link1](https://www-wake--up--neo-net.translate.goog/es/javascript/firebase-tools-getaddrinfo-enotfound-metadata.google.internal/806961951/?_x_tr_sl=es&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=sc,in) and [link2](https://www.angularfix.com/2022/01/error-fetching-access-token-error-while.html)